# How to implement NCHW format automatically for customized operators?

Tags: tensorflow

I built a GPU-enabled tensorflow. When I feed NHWC images (or feature maps) to tf.nn.conv2d, I found that in the corresponding C++ kernel, Conv2DOp::Compute() , it transformed NHWC to NCHW automatically. I also
defined a new customized operator that accepts feature maps as input:

```
REGISTER_OP("RegionOp")
.Input("value: T")
.Output("output: T")
.Attr("T: {half, bfloat16, float, double}")
.SetShapeFn(......);
```

However, I found in my customized operator kernel, RegionOp::Compute(), the feature maps format is always NHWC.

Is it possible to transform NHWC to NCHW automatically in new customized operators as tf.nn.conv2d (Conv2DOp) does?

Thank you very much!